# Ubuntu 15.10 not detecting external blu-ray drive

Tags: 15.10, dvd, blu-ray

Running Ubuntu 15.10 and its not detecting my Samsung SE-506BB external blu-ray drive.

Do i have to mount it in any way?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo lshw -C storage -C disk`?

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not have to be mounted to be detected by the system.